# Nth string match and then delete following string and put a new string instead by sed

Tags: string, sed

I have this file:

```
  "Max": 10,
  "Enable": true,
  "Min": 2,
  "Enable": true,
  "Retries": 5,
```

I want to change the second occurrence Enable value by deleting all after "Enable": and put the value I need.
I don't care which value is right now in "Enable" just to replace even if I replace with the same string.

I used this command:

```
sed -re 's/("Enable":)[^:]/\1 false,/2' file > newfile
```

But the result I get:

```
  "Max": 10,
  "Enable": true,
  "Min": 2,
  "Enable": false,true,
  "Retries": 5,
```

I need it using sed command if it possible.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

I know you said you want sed but sed is for simple substitutions on a single line, which this is not, so you should be using awk:

```
$ awk '/Enable/ && (++c==2) {$2="false,"} 1' file
"Max": 10,
"Enable": true,
"Min": 2,
"Enable": false,
"Retries": 5,
```

Comment: Could maybe use a stricter regex, but something like this is a sane way.

Comment: Agreed on the regex, but I didn't want to put much effort into this since the OP had already stated they wanted a sed solution.

Comment: Simple and clean (+1)

Answer (score 2):

This is rather more roundabout in sed than it would be in awk, but okay. The idea you're having is not bad, but you run into the problem that sed works in a line-based manner: sed reads a line into the pattern space, runs your code on it, then reads the next line. Barring special handling, your code only ever sees one line at a time, so it doesn't see that the second occurrence of `"Enable":` is the second occurrence.

The easy way around that, if the file is small enough to be held fully in RAM, is to read the file fully into RAM before working on it:

```
sed ':a $! { N; ba }; s/\("Enable":\)[^\n]*/\1 false,/2' filename
```

That is:

```
:a                                  # jump label for looping
$! {                                # Unless the end of input was reached
  N                                 # fetch the next line, append it
  ba                                # go to :a
}                                   # this reads the whole file into the
                                    # pattern space. Then:
s/\("Enable":\)[^\n]*/\1 false,/2   # replace second occurrence of a matching
                                    # value.
```

If you're using Mac OS X or a BSD: those come with BSD sed, which requires some...ah...persuasion to work with jump instructions. I believe it should accept

```
sed -e ':a' -e '$! { N; ba' -e '}; s/\("Enable":\)[^\n]*/\1 false,/2' filename
```

Alternatively,

```
sed '1h; 1!H; $!d; x; s/\("Enable":\)[^\n]*/\1 false,/2' filename
```

does very nearly the same thing, except it assembles the file in the hold buffer rather than the pattern space.

If the file is very large, you can use

```
sed '1 { x; s/^/../; x; }; /"Enable":/ { x; /^.$/ { x; s/:.*/: false,/; x; }; s/.//; x; }' filename
```

This works as follows:

```
1 {                  # in the first line
   x                 # set a counter in the hold buffer
   s/^/../           # two dots here to replace the second occurrence.
   x                 # (use n dots to replace the nth)
}
/"Enable":/ {        # in a matching line:
  x                  
  /^.$/ {            # check the counter. If it is one,
    x
    s/:.*/: false,/  # replace value
    x
  }
  s/.//              # decrease counter
  x
}
```

`x` swaps the hold buffer and pattern space, so that the contents of the hold buffer are in the pattern space and can be worked with. The lot of them see to it that the right stuff is in the pattern space at the right time.

Comment: plus 1 for the statement `rather more roundabout` :-).

Comment: @EdMorton The counter code is actually not so bad in terms of complexity. You have to persuade yourself to read the `x` instructions as a sort of special brace, a pair of which denote a block where you're working on the other buffer. This is generally the trick to reading more complex sed code: you very nearly always see stuff of the form `x; yadda; yadda; x`. (When you don't, that's where the headscratching begins in earnest)

Comment: Appreciate the tip but to be completely honest I'm just not interested in learning how to do stuff like this with sed since awk's always available and IMHO almost always results in a better solution in every significant way (and most insignificant ones!). I really don't understand why anyone uses sed for more than, essentially, `s/old/new` other than maybe just for the mental exercise.

Comment: There are a couple of blind spots in awk where sed is more straightforward (I'm aware that more often this runs the other way), such as `s///2` or the lack of back references (except in gawk's `gensub`) or `y///`, and writing portable awk is even more painful than writing portable sed because at least one common awk (a version of mawk) doesn't adhere fully to POSIX. Mind you, some put forward the idea that both are superseded by Perl, so we better close down both of them, eh? :P

Comment: Good solutions and discussions! +1

Comment: @Wintermute IMHO instead of `y///` you should use `tr` but as I mentioned, you should use sed for `s///`, including `s///2` and as you pointed out gawk (and I think mawk now) has `gensub()`. Some versions of sed don't adhere to POSIX either, e.g. the default sed on Solaris. Finally - many of the machines I use at work don't and AFAIK never will have have perl on them (idk why, admin...) so lets not retire sed and awk just yet :-).

Answer (score 0):

**(Updated)**
The solutions presented in this answer, are reading the full document into the memory...

With Perl: after two "Enables", substitute `.*` with `false`:

```
perl -p0E 's!"Enable" (.|\n)*? "Enable": \K .* ! false!x'
```

In (gnu)Sed, in using `-z` (registers separated by NULL char) the file will became
a single register. In this situation a solution (similar to OP tentative) can be used:

```
sed -zr 's!"Enable":[^\n]*!"Enable": false!2'
or
sed -zr 's!("Enable":)[^\n]*!\1 false!2'
```

Using the Perl strategy is not valid in sed because we don't have non-greedy regexp operators (like `.*?`). So the

```
sed -zr 's!("Enable"(.|\n)*?"Enable":)[^\n]*!\1 false!' ### WRONG
```

Is wrong: it works just if we have 2 occurrences of "Enable"

Comment: @EdMorton, OK thanks (I know! I meant the solutions presented in my answer -- I will change my ambigous sentence)

Comment: Hum. I'm not a big fan of the null-byte splitting; the data in the question looks vaguely JSON-ish, where null bytes in strings are allowed (if rare). In the Perl case, that can be fixed easily with `-0777` instead of `-0`; for the sed case we'd end with something very similar to the stuff I put up. Apart from that, a drawback of the Perl solution is that it's more tedious to adapt for the nth occurrence (as asked in the question title, though not in the question text). Since counter variables exist in Perl, I see no reason to slurp and do the whole thing in one 's///'.

Comment: Something like EdMorton's awk solution should be trivially portable to Perl, and it's in my opinion the better algorithm. Mind you, if the input data really *is* JSON, neither sed nor awk should be used at all, and with Perl a JSON library should be employed (although that could be overkill; first I'd try with `jq` in that case).